# .NET Core application to connect with Windows Server 2012 R2 ADFS (Version 3.0) supporting OAUTH 2.0 authorization protocol

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

I am trying to create a login mvc application in .NET through which any identity provider that supports OpenIdConnect for authentication and Oauth2.0 for authorization should be able to communicate. The objective is all my microservices will then call the login service ( which will act as a proxy) to perform single login and single logout and authorization via different identity providers such as Ping Identity or Okta or perhaps Azure AD. I am using the package   **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect** to achieve this.
I don't have much experience setting up ADFS authentication in the .NET stack so forgive my ignorance if I am missing the obvious. But if some one can point me in the direction on how to configure ADFS and write a .NET Core application to request Oauth2.0 supported tokens from it, would help a lot. Please know that I am trying to connect with ADFS 2012 R2 , which supports Oauth2.0  Authorization code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADFS 2012 R2 does not support OpenID Connect and has no concept of an ID token.

You need to use ADFS 2016 or above.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But ADFS 2012 R2 does support Oauth Auth Code flow. Can I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication package to create a middleware for authorization?

Comment: The problem with 2012 R2 is that only the deprecated ADAL library works with it and I suspect ASP.NET Core uses the later MSAL library.